# T-trees: why are they not used for on-disk indexing?

Tags: data-structures

I've been researching B+ trees and T-trees lately. There seems to be a trend in which B+ trees are used for on-disk indexes and T-trees are used in memory.

I believe it is due to disk I/Os, but I can't find anything confirming that notion. Am I correct in that assumption?

Also, if disk accesses for T-trees could be limited to log B via caching, couldn't they outperform B+ trees at logB N?

Comment: If you limit to log B via caching then you are essentially saying that the number of nodes read is independent of the index size.  For argument's sake, fix B=2 so your index has to be big enough that only the last node gets read.  I think that means all of your internal nodes must fit in the cache.  Back to the arbitrary size index and you have an arbitrary size cache.

Comment: @DrC, you are exactly right. Say only the min/max values and child pointers of each node are cached which means that B can be much larger while the memory cost remains constant for each node in the tree. Lets say you need 64 bytes to cache the min/max/left/right for each node and B=128. Based on log(N/B) for N=1024 and B=128 the height should be log2(1024/128) or 3 with 7 total nodes (2^h - 1). So with 7 nodes and 64 bytes per node that's only 448 bytes. Therefore, the mem cost grows with the node count not N. Which leads to your conclusion that only the last node is read from disk at log B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The T-Tree is essentially a binary tree.  So the tree depth is something like log2(N/B) for the T-Tree vs. logB(N) for the B+Tree (N=#data items, B=number of keys stored in each node=branch factor for B+Tree).  These are approximate as neither tree has a fixed number of items in each node. Anyway, for large N, the B+Tree will win handily on that metric.  Under the assumption of uniform memory access, that figure doesn't matter but it really matters on secondary storage where it is roughly the number of secondary storage accesses.  It also matters on modern machines with hierarchical memory (the original T-Tree paper tested on a Vax 11/750).

I make assumptions above surrounding how you update both structures for the respective environments.   I believe they are symmetric and fair.  Primarily I assume that data and keys are stored by reference in memory and by copy on secondary storage.  Failure to adjust the structures in that way would be disastrous for the T-tree, which has uniform access cost as the core of its design, as each key compare would require external access.  For non-fixed size data, some other packing adjustments are needed in both cases (and used in the real world).